# Sandboxing Javascript code

Tags: javascript, sandbox

I am working on a game in Javascript, and I would like to be able to include a modding API. How can I allow a developer to execute arbitrary code using my API while keeping them from doing malicious activities (stealing cookies, redirecting to a malicious site)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [project by Google](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) that aims to allow you to do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on something like this and my solution was to run the script-ables inside an iFrame that points to a subdomain (http://bar.foo.com) instead of the main site (http://foo.com).  Input is provided to the script via url #fragment#identifiers and output is provided through the URL fragment identifier of a nested, invisible iFrame pointing back at the original name.

Remember, you can set a child frame's URL even if you can't see it, and you can always check a frame's specific URL if it's on the same domain.